# I have been trying to write a program python

Tags: algorithm, python-3.x, split

I have been trying to write a program a simple program without importing any library. I simply want to print the following strings in this array in vertical form without using any complex algorithm. I will be glad if anyone can help me please.
['San Francisco', 'Christchurch ', 'Sydney ', 'Bangkok ', 'Copenhagen ']

Comment: S C S B C 
a h y a o 
n r d n p
  i n  g e 
F s e k n 
r t y o h 
a c   k a n 
h g c u e 
i r     n 
s c 
c h 
o

Comment: #This is what I did and its printing the whole thing #vertically.
def main(): Cities = ['Paris ','Washington','­Accra ','Beijing ','Milan ']

for i in range (len(Cities[1])): for city in Cities: print(city[0])
main()

Comment: Is that output somehow useful?

Comment: For your info: I voted -1, for the worst title I've ever seen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using some built-in functions, like `max()`, `len()` and `zip()`:

```
L = ['San Francisco', 'Christchurch ', 'Sydney ', 'Bangkok ', 'Copenhagen ']

max_length = len(max(L, key = lambda x : len(x)))

new_L = []

for e in L:
    new_L.append(e + ' ' * (max_length - len(e)))

for e in zip(*new_L):
    for el in e:
        if el != ' ':
            print el,
```

**Output:**

```
S C S B C a h y a o n r d n p i n g e F s e k n r t y o h a c k a n h g c u e i r n s c c h o
```

---

The lines:

```
new_L = []

for e in L:
    new_L.append(e + ' ' * (max_length - len(e)))
```

can be written with list comprehension like:

```
new_L = [e + ' ' * (max_length - len(e)) for e in L]
```

**Edit:**

```
L = ['San Francisco', 'Christchurch ', 'Sydney ', 'Bangkok ', 'Copenhagen ']

# Get the maximum length of a string in the list
max_length = len(max(L, key = lambda x : len(x)))
#print max(L, key = lambda x : len(x)) # get the maximum of the list based in length
#print max_length

# Iterate through indices of max_length: 0, 1, 2, 3 ...
for i in range(max_length):
    # Iterate through each city in the list
    for city in L:
        # If the index is < than the length of the city
        if  i < len(city) and city[i] != ' ':
            print city[i],
```

Comment: wow..thats not simple lol. i am new to python so its hard understanding. thank you so much.

Comment: Ok, see edit, here is a simpler way. I will try to explain it.

Comment: thanks Christian. I am just short of words. Thank you.